# Knockout Validation Text Only

Tags: knockout.js

Im having trouble with Knockout validation. Im trying to make my "Name" input textbox be text only, ive searched on google but seem to find nothing I could understand.

Could someone please help.

Knockout Code

```
self.addProduct = function () {
    self.modelView.Id("");
    self.modelView.Name("");
    self.modelView.Address("");
    $('#addCustomer').modal('show');
}
```

Code inside my Pop Up model

```
<p>Name: <input data-bind="value:modelView.Name" /></p>
            <p>Address: <input data-bind="value:modelView.Address" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)

```
self.Name = ko.observable().extend({ pattern: '^[a-zA-Z].$' });
```

You can then use any pattern you like, eg. no Numbers `/^([^0-9]*)$/`

You can easily test out your regex here http://regexpal.com/